# How to update react variable state?

Tags: reactjs, react-state-management

I am trying to update the state of the variable "selectedPlayer" however when I setState function the state of this variable does not update, I have tested this through console logs as you can see below.

Below is how I am trying to set the state of the variable and the some of this class file for your knowledge

```
 this.setState({ selectPlayer: player });
```

this is some of the Component file and a function which i am using to update the state.

```
  class StatApp extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {

          selectedPlayer: 'dassdasda',

        };
        this.selectPlayer = this.selectPlayer.bind(this);
      }

    selectPlayer = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        //  console.log(e.target.value); //will give you the value continue

        // Store Value
        const selectPlayer = this.state.selectedPlayer;
        console.log(this.state.selectedPlayer);

        console.log(selectPlayer);

        // Test to see if we are getting the value from the playerButton 
        const player = e.target.value;
        console.log(player);


        this.setState({ selectPlayer: player });

        console.log(selectPlayer);

      };
```

Comment: State is updated, however it's done asynchronously. When you call `console.log()` the state is not updated yet. Also, do not bind the `selectPlayer` to `this` if you're using arrow functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

setState is asynchronous, so when you are console logging it, state has not yet been updated. You can use the callback form of setState to get the updated state:

```
this.setState(
    { selectPlayer: player },
    () => console.log(this.state.selectPlayer)
);
```

Comment: so how can I obtain the new update state since setState is asynchronous , as i will be sending the variable value to my database?

Comment: In this arrow function passed as a second argument to 'setState` you can do it. But if you want to send this new value to you database, you don't have to wait for state to send it, you can just use the `player` value. Another thing to keep in mind is that if the update to the database fails for any reson you should be reverting state in React.

Comment: Just to clarify, this arrow function runs after the state is updated, so you can use `this.state.whatever` as usual and you will get the updated state.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it'a typo.
try changing

```
 this.setState({ selectPlayer: player });
```

to

```
this.setState({ selectedPlayer: player });
```

**Find the other answer for the updated state not being printed on console**.